awk - Character Class Regex gsub Changes output
Parsing the following with awk:
$> df -h  /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          476G  370G  106G  78% /

If I use an explicit match for the G's on the values, it works as expected:
$> awk -v indrive="/dev/sda1" 'NR!=1{gsub(/G/,""); print $2,$4,indrive}' <(df -h /)
476 106 /dev/sda1

However, if I genericize it w/a char class:
awk -v indrive="/dev/sda1" 'NR!=1{gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,""); print $2,$4,indrive}' <(df -h /)
370 78% /dev/sda1

Not sure where 370 and 78% are coming from.
Update: I actually get the same from:
awk -v indrive="/dev/sda1" 'NR!=1{gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/,""); print $2,$4,indrive}' <(df -h /)
370 78% /dev/sda1

But with [[:upper:]] it seems to work fine:
awk -v indrive="/dev/sda1" 'NR!=1{gsub("([[:upper:]])*",""); print $2,$4,indrive}' <(df -h /)
476 106 /dev/sda1


with alpha, you delete rootfs. after a gsub, using $ causes a resplit so when you subsequently access $2 it no longer refers to the same column

consider: echo 1 2 3 4 5 | awk '{gsub(/[134]/,"");printf "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}'

in this particular case, you could probably strip the fields without gsub: awk -v indrive="/dev/sda1" 'NR!=1{print $2+0,$4+0,indrive}' <(df -h /). note that numbers output by this and your code may be unexpected if you have filesystems with M or T size, for example

It seems like this is what you're trying to do, using any awk (and cat file in place of your df command for demoing):
$ cat file |
awk -v indrive='/dev/sda1' 'NR>1{$0=$2 FS $4; gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,""); print $0, indrive}'
476 106 /dev/sda1

or this with GNU awk for gensub():
$ cat file |
awk -v indrive='/dev/sda1' 'NR>1{print gensub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"","g",$2 FS $4), indrive}'
476 106 /dev/sda1

Your code was applying the gsub() across the whole line and so removing $1 and re-splitting $0 into different fields while the above is selecting the input fields first, then doing gsub() on just them.
Regarding:

Not sure where 370 and 78% are coming from.

They're the 3rd and 5th fields from your input after G is removed:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs          476G  370G  106G  78% /
                      ^^^         ^^^

Regarding:

gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"")...
...Update: I actually get the same from...
gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/,"")...

The character ranges a-z and A-Z together cover the same set of alphabetic characters present in your input as [:alpha:] does. In some locales they're identical sets of characters.
Regarding your comment:

I thought it was just going to apply gsub to $0 and leave the fields
intact if possible. Still not sure why [:upper:] and G alone work as
expected but I guess that's another question.

[[:upper:]] (the set of all upper case letters) and G worked because they only match the Gs you want to remove from your input while [[:alpha:]] matches each of the 6 characters in rootfs (lower case letters) in addition to the Gs and so it also removed that whole first field.

Thanks - I thought it was just going to apply gsub to $0 and leave the fields intact if possible. Still not sure why [:upper:] and G alone work as expected but I guess that's another question.

It apparently eats the first field for [:alpha:]*, got it down to:  awk -v indrive='/dev/sda1' 'NR>1{gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,""); print $1,$3,indrive}' <(df -h /)

I added an explanation to my answer of why [[:upper:]] and G worked for you and why [[:alpha:]] removes the first field.

That code in your comment will fail if/when the first field contains a non-alphabetic character, e.g. 7 or _ or # (as you suggested in another comment could occur) any other non-alphabetic character.

gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,"") completely removes the first field and changes what $2 and $4 refer to. See:
$ awk -v indrive="/dev/sda1" 'NR!=1{gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,""); print $0}' <(df -h /)
          476  370  106  78% /

To change only specific fields, you should do:
gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/, "", $2)
gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/, "", $4)
print $2, $4, indrive

or, in this case:
tmp = $2 OFS $4
gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/, "", tmp)
print tmp, indrive


I was trying to keep it concise, this works too. I finally settled on: awk -v indrive='/dev/sda1' 'NR>1{$1=1$1;gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/,""); print $2,$4,indrive}' <(df -h /) because I don't want to see the day that $1 doesn't disappear because there's a # in it.

Observe that -h in df -h  / according to man page of df stands for --human-readable. If you must to parse output of df AT ANY PRICE I suggest to NOT use that option, you can easily divide values to get desired unit for example
df / | awk 'NR>1{print $1, "has", $4 / 1024, "free MB"}'

Will always report about free space in MB. This approach allows to avoid erratic behavior where different units are used in df output.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)
